# PAX-CDI: CdiContainerFactory and BundleTracker

Tags: java, osgi, cdi, pax

I use felix and pax-cdi 0.13 and weld. I have two bundles A in B. In bundle A I have BundleTracker and Customizer, in bundle B I have CDI beans. So I want in bundle tracker to get cdi beans from bundle B using bean manager. So I have method in customizer:

```
@Override
    public Object addingBundle(Bundle bundle, BundleEvent event) {
        String marker = (String) bundle.getHeaders().get("Some-Marker");
        if (marker != null) {
            try {
                //1 we get CdiContainerFactory
                BundleContext thisBundleContext=FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
                ServiceReference<?> sr = thisBundleContext.getServiceReference(CdiContainerFactory.class.getName());
                CdiContainerFactory cdiContainerFactory = (CdiContainerFactory) thisBundleContext.getService(sr);
                if (cdiContainerFactory==null){
                    System.out.println("Cdi container factory is null");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Cdi container factory is not null");
                }
                //2 we get BeanManager from CdiContainerFactory
                Class<?> klass  = bundle.loadClass("com.temp.Temp");
                BeanManager beanManager = cdiContainerFactory.getContainer(bundle).getBeanManager();
                Bean<?> bean = (Bean<?>)beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(klass));
                Object temp= beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ExtenderBundleTracker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return bundle;
    }
```

To register bundle tracker I use the following code:

```
bundleTracker=new BundleTracker<>(context, Bundle.ACTIVE, new MyCustomizer());
```

The code above works. But not always. I have timing problem. I always get `Cdi container factory is not null`, but the following line

```
BeanManager beanManager = cdiContainerFactory.getContainer(bundle).getBeanManager();
```

sometimes throws NullPointerException. 
As I suppose when Bundle B becomes active CDI container is still not ready for it. How can such problem be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the bean manager sometimes cannot be found is due to the fact that the CDI container is (asynchronously) created by a bundle listener from the PAX-CDI bundles as well. This means that you may run into a race condition because the container may or may not be created at the time your bundle listener is called.

When using PAX-CDI, I would not recommend trying to access the bean manager, but in stead export the bean you need as an OSGi service (@OsgiServiceProvider annotation on the bean) and track that service via a `ServiceTracker`. If that is not possible because of the scope of the bean, you can always create a separate factory pattern bean in the container that does the bean creation work for you and export that one as a service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From your explanation can I state that when OSGi service (created using @OsgiServiceProvider) of bundle A is registered in OSGi service registry then 100% that Bean Manager of bundle A is ready?

Comment: I wouldn't know because I don't know the internals of PAX-CDI. Looking at your code above, I think it may be sufficient to track the `CdiContainerFactory` via a `ServiceTracker` in stead of using a bundle listener.